# Need help in the Regex issue: TypeError: cannot read property "1" from null

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

```
function numericEntityToChar(s) {
    //s="&#30331;&#20837;"  
    console.log(s);
    var chars = String.fromCharCode(s.match(/^&#(\d+);$/)[1]);
    // throws uncaught exception TypeError: cannot read property "1" from null.
    console.log(chars);
    return chars; 
}
```

I have never worked with REGEX and this one just not helping as a 1st one either. Help needed on this.

Comment: It means that your regular expression is not matching anything, so it returns `null`. Then you are trying to look at index 1 of `null`.

Comment: Note that `^` and `$` mean the beginning and the end of the string, respectively, so your regex won't match a string with more than one entity in it.

Comment: The two codes are supposed to be UNICODE which basically translates to some Chinese characters. In order to be processed/displayed in JavaScript I am using this approach. If not, this is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do that?

Comment: Why would you need to do regex voodoo to display unicode characters …?

Comment: @CBroe Yeah. This is one instance in the page where a pre-loaded button text needs to be replaced onLoad by reading from the property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try setting it up this way:

```
function numericEntityToChar(s) {
    var re = /&#(\d+);/g,
        ret = "", match;
    while (match = re.exec(s)) {
        ret += String.fromCharCode(match[1]);
    }
    return ret;
}

var str = "&#30331;&#20837;";
console.log(numericEntityToChar(str));
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XDGk9/

The `^` and `$` anchoring wouldn't allow global/multiple matching, and the regex wouldn't return the actual numbers with `.match()`.

Comment: Great. That works in the jsfiddle as expected. But the issue is when I use the same in the JS the '&' converts to '&amp;' and the solutions fails to work.

Comment: That’s a different problem then – so please describe it in a way that makes it comprehensible.

Comment: The solution works fine. But when used in my code the line 
`var re = /&#(\d+);/g`
changes to
`var re = /&amp;#(\d+);/g`

Comment: @AbhinandanSahu Well how is your Javascript put on that page? Whatever server you're using seems to encode the characters

Comment: @Ian Well, the JS code is in a JSP which is included in another JSP page. Will it causing this issue?

Comment: @AbhinandanSahu I guess it has to be, if you have `&` in the JSP and it's being changed to `&amp;` in the output HTML. You could try using `<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ /* CODE HERE */ //]]></script>` but I don't know if that would fix it.

Comment: @Ian Funny thing is I already have the JS code `CDATA` wrapped. Still I have the issue. It has to on the JSP side. I've to tweak some encoding settings.

Answer (score 3):

The exception means that `s.match` is reutrning null.  That means the regex isn't matching.

Your regex, `/^&#(\d+);$/`, expects to match a string contiaining single entity (ampersand-hash-number-semicolon), but your string contains two.  You can change your regex to get it to match  correctly, either to match the first one, the second one, or both.

EDIT:

You can use string.replace to replace the entities with the regex.  This is useful if there are other characters in the string:

```
s = "a&#30331;bc&#20837;d"
s.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function(match, char) {
    return String.fromCharCode(char)
});
// == "a登bc入d"
```

Comment: and how would you change that regex!

Comment: What's you goal?  Do you want to capture the first entity, the last one, all of them, ...?

Comment: @kevingessner all of them.

Comment: I would @Ian's solution, above -- that appears to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Do not anchor your regex:

```
/&#(\d+);/
```

Answer (score 0):

When there are no matches found, the `match` method returns null, this is what's probably happening to you.